# Spring Cloud Stream dynamic destination partitionCount property

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I would like to use the `BinderAwareChannelResolver` bean in order to send message to Kafka with a topic name that is resolved on runtime.
My problem is that the `partitionCount` in the `BindingProperties` of this topic defaults to 1. 
 This value does not reflect the true number of partitions when this topic already existed in Kafka and also when this topic is created by the client (with partition count equal to the `minPartitionCount` configuration value). 
How can I make this property reflect the true number of partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BindingProperties are never updated to reflect the physical topic configuration; the properties are used for configuration only.

With 2.0, you can use a `NewBindingCallback<KafkaProducerProperties>` to modify the properties for a dynamic destination - see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#dynamicdestination).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I observed that the partition key extractor isn't used during the determination of what partition to send the message to when using a dynamic channel. I did something wrong? Or it's intentionally implemented this way?

Comment: Also if the partition count of a topic are updated by another service/manually,  outbound channels that were already registered will keep sending messages to  the old partitions and new partitions will be empty until we restart the service?

Comment: The key extractor should work ok; if it's not, open a GItHub issue showing your code/configuration. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/309) to detect the actual partition count but it will not be easy to fix. In any case, even it that worked or you manually fix the count in the properties, yes, you'd have to restart the producer for the new count to take effect.